# Nested Linq queries Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have three models in my azure model. One model basically maps the other two. Here are my models

```
public class Organization : EntityModel
{

    public String Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RowKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RowKey = value;
        }
    }

    ......
}

public class OrganizationGroup : EntityModel
{

    public String Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RowKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RowKey = value;
        }
    }

    .......
}
```

Now here is the mapping class

```
class OrganizationGroupMapping : EntityModel
{
    public String OrganizationId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PartitionKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.PartitionKey = value;
        }
    }

    public String OrganizationGroupId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RowKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RowKey = value;
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

Now I am trying to make a function which will give me all the organizations in a particular organization group. I can use a for loop, which I am doing now like this

```
    public IEnumerable<Organization> GetOrganizations()
    {
        List<Organization> org = new List<Organization>();

        foreach (OrganizationGroupMapping ogm in OrganizationGroupMapping.GetByOrganizationGroupId(Id))
        {
            org.Add(ogm.GetOrganization());
        }

        return org;
    }
```

The above function is being called from OrganizationGroup class. I am trying to use linq as it seems more cleaner. But not sure how to do that. Any help in this regard?

Comment: What's wrong with `GetOrganizations()`? It seems pretty clean to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use **[System.Linq.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891.aspx)** which will create a new object with implicit type of `GetOrganization()`.

```
public IEnumerable<Organization> GetOrganizations()
{
    var organizations = OrganizationGroupMapping.GetByOrganizationGroupId(Id)
                        .Select(org => ogm.GetOrganization());
    return organizations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should study about [Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) And [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx)

```
public class Organization
{

    public String Id  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationGroup> OrganizationGroups { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationGroup
{

    public String Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

**The On your context :**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasMany(l => l.OrganizationGroups).WithMany(t => t.Organizations).Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("OrganizationId");
            m.MapRightKey("OrganizationGroupId");
            m.ToTable("OrganizationGroupMapping ");
        });
    }
```

**Usage :**

```
Context.Organizations.Include("OrganizationGroups").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I can't see how you define your partition key on your OrganizationGroup and Organization entity.

I understand that an organization belong to a organization group ? If it's correct you can build your entity like that :

Because dealing with Azure storage table we have :

- PartitionKey + rowKey  = unicity of a line

To have a unique OrganizationGroup , the Id map the partition key but we let the rowKey empty.

```
public class OrganizationGroup : TableEntity
{
    public OrganizationGroup()
    {
        this.RowKey = string.Empty;
    }
    public String Id
    {
        get { return this.PartitionKey; }
        set { this.PartitionKey = value; }
    }
}
```

Because an organization belong to an organizationGroup, the PartitionKey of the Organization entity is the partition key of the organizationGroup (see [Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/), look at the One-to-many relationships section) :

```
public class Organization : TableEntity
{
    public String OrganizationGroupId
    {
        get { return this.PartitionKey; }
        set { this.PartitionKey = value; }
    }

    public String Id
    {
        get { return this.RowKey; }
        set { this.RowKey = value; }
    }
}
```

So you don't need a mapping table anymore : you can retrieve your organization by OrganizationGroupId (= PartitionKey) directly :

```
public static List<Organization> GetByOrganizationGroupId(string organizationGroupId)
{
    var org = new List<Organization>();
    // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Create the table client.
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "Organization" table.
    CloudTable organizationTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("Organization");

    // Construct the query operation for all OrganizationGroupMapping entities where PartitionKey="organizationGroupId".
    var query = new TableQuery<Organization>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, organizationGroupId));

    // Return the organizations
    return organizationTable.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
}
```